# Is it safe to open SLOAD to any contract?

Tags: solidity, assembly

I am running into issue of contract size over the limit when deploying my contract. So, I have decided to open SLOAD in my getter so that any contract can read from it.

```
function readBySlot(uint256 slot) external view override returns(bytes32 value) {
        assembly {
            value := sload(slot)
        }
    }
```

With this I can remove most of my getters(which I have plenty) and do a workaround by getting the storage slots values in other contract and using assembly create the required struct or variables.

Comment: you pay for the getters only during deployment, which is not much (considering the function will be very small) , but later you will get values with hardcoded key slots. Also solidity can pack many different variables into single slot so you must implement yoru own decoding function. So, it is not much advantage in exporting single instruction

Comment: if you are running into binary size limit then use `optimize` flag with `solc` command, or split functionality into different contracts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All data on the chain is public anyhow. If someone wanted to, he could get these values without your getter by using **web3.eth.getStorageAt()**.

So I don't see this as a major vulnerability except if you don't want your values to be accessed by other on-chain protocols.

Answer (score 1):

Using Solidity Assembly for view functions is completely safe, unless you are planning to consume those functions inside the smart contracts themselves. I still consider it an anti-pattern though for the following reasons:

1. Needing to remember what variables the storage slots map to.
2. Possibly setting a restriction for how you add new storage variables so that the old order of slots remain intact.

Instead of having to forgoing the nice features of Solidity that make it a fully-fledged programming language, I would suggest trying out the following in order to handle the smart contract size issue:

1. Turn on the optimizer and increase the optimizer runs for the compiler.
2. Split large smart contracts into smaller ones.

Comment: Hi Ahmed. Thanks for your answer.

The only reason I am thinking of using it is that I will have bunch of getters in another contract that calls the slot of the storage and using assembly constructs it to required variable/struct. I know it seems like an anti-pattern but I am only using it for viewing and the storage slots will be constant as well.